# Trouble setting up Ingress with Elastic ECK

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I'm having trouble setting up a working ingress for ElasticSearch on kubernetes. I'm using their own `CustomResourceDefinition` i.e `x.k8s.elastic.co/v1beta1`.

My `elastic.yaml` looks like this: (`ingress.yaml` is included at the bottom)

```
apiVersion: elasticsearch.k8s.elastic.co/v1beta1
kind: Elasticsearch
metadata:
  name: elasticsearch-test
  namespace: elastic-system
spec:
  version: 7.4.0
  #http:
  #  tls:
  #    certificate:
  #      secretName: tls-secret-test
  http:
    service:
      spec:
        type: ClusterIP
    tls:
      selfSignedCertificate:
        disabled: true
  nodeSets:
  - name: master
    count: 1
    nodeSelector:
      component: elasticsearch
    volumeClaimTemplates:
    - metadata:
        name: elasticsearch-master
      spec:
        accessModes:
        - ReadWriteOnce
        resources:
          requests:
            storage: 5Gi
        storageClassName: multik8s-nfs-storage
    - metadata:
        name: elasticsearch-data
      spec:
        accessModes:
        - ReadWriteOnce
        resources:
          requests:
            storage: 5Gi
        storageClassName: multik8s-nfs-storage
    config:
      node.master: true
      node.data: true
      node.ingest: true
      node.store.allow_mmap: false
'''
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
  name: elasticsearch
  namespace: elastic-system
spec:
  tls:
    - hosts:
      - elasticsearch.foo.bar
      secretName: tls-secret
  rules:
    - host: elasticsearch.foo.bar
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /
            backend:
              serviceName: elasticsearch-test-es-http
              servicePort: 9200
```

And my `kibana.yaml` looks like this:

```
apiVersion: kibana.k8s.elastic.co/v1beta1
kind: Kibana
metadata:
  name: kibana-test
  namespace: elastic-system
spec:
  version: 7.4.0
  #http:
  #  tls:
  #    certificate:
  #      secretName: tls-secret-test
  http:
    service:
      spec:
        type: ClusterIP
    tls:
      selfSignedCertificate:
        disabled: true
  count: 1
  elasticsearchRef:
    name: elasticsearch-test
'''
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
  name: kibana
  namespace: elastic-system
spec:
  tls:
    - hosts:
      - kibana.foo.bar
      secretName: tls-secret
  rules:
    - host: kibana.foo.bar
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /
            backend:
              serviceName: kibana-test-kb-http
              servicePort: 5601
```

First of all, I do have my own signed tls cert i want to use in the ingress.
The wierd thing is that the ingress for *kibana* works straight out the box, without any problems. The ingress for elasticsearch *only* works while I'm on the same network as the k8s cluster. Not outside of it.

```sh
curl -u "elastic:$PASSWORD" -k "https://elasticsearch.foo.bar"
curl: (7) Failed to connect to elasticsearch.foo.bar port 443: Connection refused
```

On the same network I'm getting

```sh
curl -u "elastic:$PASSWORD" -k "https://elasticsearch.foo.bar"
{
  "name" : "elasticsearch-test-es-master-0",
  "cluster_name" : "elasticsearch-test",
  "cluster_uuid" : "ulfFb-tjT8KplEBPSglo6w",
  "version" : ...
}
```

I've experimented some by setting

```
tls:
  selfSignedCertificate:
    subjectAltNames:
      - dns: elasticsearch.foo.bar
```

and

```
tls:
  certificate:
    secretName: tls-secret-test
```

without success... But I'm guessing thats used for internal traffic, i.e between *kibana* and *elasticsearch*?

I'm not really sure what I'm doing wrong since it's working with Kibana but not ElasticSearch...

P.s both kibana and elastics healts are green:
i.e

```sh
NAME                         HEALTH   NODES   VERSION   PHASE   AGE
elasticsearch-test   green    1       7.4.0     Ready   1d
NAME                  HEALTH   NODES   VERSION   AGE
kibana-test   green    1       7.4.0     1d
```

Answer (score 2):

If tls is deactivated, try to request without https

```
 http:
service:
  spec:
    type: ClusterIP
tls:
  selfSignedCertificate:
    disabled: true
```

With this command

```
curl -u "elastic:$PASSWORD" -k "http://elasticsearch.foo.bar"
```

Here my ingress (working fine without  tls)

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
 # remove comment if tls is activated
 # annotations:
 #   nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/backend-protocol: HTTPS
 #   nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/secure-backends: "true"
  name: elastic-ingress
spec:
  rules:
  - host: elasticsearch.foo.bar 
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: 
          servicePort: 9200
        path: /
  tls:
  - hosts:
    - elasticsearch.foo.bar
    secretName: tls
```